# Can send/Can't read .NET serial port

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# serialport and hyperterminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830135/c-sharp-serialport-and-hyperterminal)

### Problem

I'm having trouble with my serial connection. I can send data to my device, but I can't read data. If I use Hyperterm, everyting work fine - I see the data coming in and going out.

Using my code, however, my serial port object never receives any data, but data I send is received by the device.

Any ideas?

### Project Info:

- WPF
- .NET 3.5 (not the Client Profile version)
- Developing on Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2010
- DA-15 serial to USB

### Hyperterm settings:

- COM20
- Bits per second: 115200
- Data bits: 8
- Parity: None
- Stop bits: 1
- Flow control: None

### C# Code:

```
SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();

serial.PortName = "COM20";
serial.BaudRate = 115200;
serial.DataBits = 8;
serial.Parity = Parity.None;
serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serial.Handshake = Handshake.None;

serial.Open();
serial.Write("Hello World\r\n");    // Echoed on device screen

while (0 == serial.BytesToRead)     // Never receive a response
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

char[] first = new char[serial.BytesToRead];
serial.Read(first, 0, first.Length);
```

### Edit:

I noted it above, but just to make sure everyone knows, I am using a USB to Serial Port cable. I don't think this is the issue because it works on Hyperterm, but just in case.

Comment: I checked and I think it is, their answer is the same as Mark's and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) they are using a seperate thread to check for Data. You can also subscribe to the [DataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) to see if it is firing at all. And there is a Community comment about setting [DTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable.aspx) and [RTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.rtsenable.aspx) to true, if the connected device needs them it will not transmit data.

Comment: Setting DTR and RTS to true resolved my read issue which was driving me crazy.